# Applying global styles in Next.js

Tags: css, typescript, styles, next.js, emotion

I am using Next.js with Typescript. The margin of the body is default 8px and I want to get it to 0px. When I try to add an external style sheet to my `index.tsx` file it throws an error that you can only add external stylesheet to `_app.tsx`. However, even when I try to import in my `_app.tsx`, it doesn't change the global style of the body. I am using Emotion css for the styling part. Is there a different way to change the style of the body in the index file using global style? Here is my `index.tsx` code and I have tried adding the global styles using Emotion CSS as well but it doesn't work.

```
class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='body'>
        <Container>
          <style jsx global>{`
            .body:global() {
              margin: 0px;
            }
          `}</style>
          <NavBar />
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need some global styles (`<style jsx global>`) to style the body element or provide css resets.

Example:

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default () => (
  <div>

    <style jsx global>{`
      body {
        background-color: red;
      }
    `}</style>

    Hello, One!
    <Link href="/two">
      <a>Go to two</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-davinci-tc13t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: It doesn't help. I have updated my code, still Next does not accept the margin of the body @ddon-90

Comment: You have `.body` which mean `class"body"` as CSS class. Remove the dot that precedes `body` if you want to target the HTML tag `<body>`.
Also `global()` is not needed. I've added a code sandbox as an example.

Comment: Could you explain what is this `<style jsx global />`? I mean, is it a feature from Next or react?

Answer (score 1):

You can have global styles using emotion with Next.js

In your _app.tsx file, you must to

```
import { Global, css } from '@emotion/core'

return (
  <>   
    <Global styles={css` /* styles */ `}/>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </>
```

You can see how to implement it, here

https://github.com/pabloobandodev/social-media/blob/master/pages/_app.tsx

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global):

> Global CSS cannot be used in files other than your Custom `<App>` due to its side-effects and ordering problems.
>
> Possible Ways to Fix It
>
> Relocate all Global CSS imports to your `pages/_app.js` file.

---

How to do this in your case?

Well, the best way is to use a CSS base, lets take [`normalize.css`](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) for example.

1. Run `yarn add normalize.css` or `npm i normalize.css`, depending on whichever you are using.
2. Add `import 'normalize.css';` in each of the page you want to use the base on. [Official Docs.](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#import-styles-from-node_modules)

Well this could seem redundant if you want to use the base in **all** of your pages. If so, you can, alternatively, create a file `page/_app.tsx` (any of the extension `.js`,`.jsx`,`.ts`,`.tsx` will work) and put this in it:

```
import 'normalize.css';

export { default } from 'next/app';
```

[**Note**](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats) : If your app is running and you just added a custom `App`, you'll need to restart the development server. Only required if `pages/_app.tsx` didn't exist before.

No need to worry about other caveats mentioned in the docs as we are simply re-exporting `App` without any modification.

There are many CSS bases available choose any that seems best for you.

---

If you want to add custom global styles, then follow this:

1. Create a file `styles/globals.css` (`.scss`,`.sass`,etc. will also work if you have [configured Next.js properly](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#customizing-sass-options)) and put your styles in that file.
2. Now add an import in `pages/_app.tsx`.

```
import '../styles/globals.css'; // change extension from `.css` to
                                // whatever you created above

export { default } from 'next/app';
```

If you have already created a [module path alias](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases) for `../styles`, then you might wanna change the styles import statement (probably to something like `import '@styles/globals.css'`).

Also, if you are using less/sass/scss and want to use a base at the same time along with your custom global styles you simply need to use an import statement in your stylesheet (no need to import the base in `_app.tsx` if imported in the global stylesheet). An example:

```
// file: styles/globals.scss
@import '../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css';

// your styles...
body {
  color: red;
}
```

```
// file: pages/_app.tsx
import '@styles/globals.scss';

export { default } from 'next/app';
```

---

Moreover, in your case it has not worked most probably because you were styling `.body` instead of `body`. It is likely that margin was present in the `body`, not your `div.body`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your _app.js, _app.tsx should look like; styles.css may have your CSS to reset the default browser properties, you can try adding other stylesheets here.

```
import '../styles/styles.css'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
   return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```